# Why is there a rounded gray gradient border around my photoshop canvas?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This border just showed up around all my canvases... is there are toggle for this view?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Photoshop preferences and change these to whichever you prefer:

[image: prefs]

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea why my photoshop decided to randomly change this setting on me. I haven't even opened preferences in ages!